# How can I express the equivalent of the is-accessible attribute using Dozer API Mappings?

Tags: dozer

The [Dozer API Mappings](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/apimappings.html) example page does not say how to specify the equivalent of the [is-accessible XML attribute](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html). Is it possible?

Comment: I am looking for the same option - placing @Mapping annotation on the field is the workaround I am using for the moment - this seems to make the field accessible

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
mapping(clazzA, clazzB).fields(
                               field("fieldnameA").accessible(true),
                               field("fieldnameB").accessible(true))
```

Comment: What about class level? is it possible?